# get values from a passed array in get url

Tags: php, arrays

I am making a web service in which the data for settings is passed inside array

```
[{"privacy_id":"74","privacy_selected_option":"public"},{"privacy_id":"77","privacy_selected_option":"public"},{"privacy_id":"177","privacy_selected_option":"public"}]
```

Now how to get values from such passed data . For normal array we use `foreach` and then get value easily .

the above values are passed inside `user_id=370&settings=[{"privacy_id":"74","privacy_selected_option":"public"},{"privacy_id":"77","privacy_selected_option":"public"},{"privacy_id":"177","privacy_selected_option":"public"}]` url like this . And i get it using `$settings=$_REQUEST['settings']`

Comment: It's just an serialized array of objects

Comment: @jean Thank you for your reply . But how can i get the value inside privacy_id and privacy_selected_option individually from each ?

Comment: json_decode(): http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: Try to unserialize: http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php

Answer (score 1):

It is `json` actually

try

```
$settings = json_decode($_REQUEST['settings']);
```

You'll get an array with objects that hold your properties.
You can loop through it

```
foreach ($settings as $setting) {
    // $setting->privacy_id...
}
```

or

```
$settings = json_decode($_REQUEST['settings'], true);

foreach ($settings as $setting) {
    // $setting['privacy_id']...
}
```

Comment: @RST note that without the `true` flag parameter in `json_decode`, you'll access properties as `->` not `$setting['privacy_id']` array indices, or just add a `true` flag

Comment: I adjusted the answer

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get the values, you can unserialise it and then access it like a normal object.

```
$settings = unserialize($_REQUEST['settings']);
//then use foreach to loop through and get the settings.
```